# How make set images slices left,center,right next to each other and grow based on content?

Tags: html, css

So I want to create an Image which is made up of three images...

Left, center and right.

The reason why I have a center image is so that the content can grow in width based on the width of parent div. The left and right image have the border outline for the image.

I was trying something like this

```css
#solutionsNav div.leadgenLeft 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    background: url(/images/leadgen_left.png) no-repeat; 
}
#solutionsNav div.leadgenRight 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    background: url(/images/leadgen_right.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

#solutionsNav div.leadgen {
    background: url(/images/leadgen_center.png) repeat-x;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

And then mark up as follows

```html
<div class="leadgenLeft">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="leadgen">
    <h3>
       <asp:Literal ID="LeadGenSpotTitleLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </h3>        
    <asp:Literal ID="LeadGenSpotDescriptionLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>        
</div> 
<div class="leadgenRight">&nbsp;</div>
```

but a few problems

1. The images are not aligning next to each other
2. The center image grabs the height of the content so is large but the left/right stay small, they need to all grow together based on the amount of content in the div
3. In the center image, the image is made of 2 shades of green where top is light green and bottom dark green. But if there is very little content only the top of the image shows so only light green shows. Is it possible that no matter what the height is, the image will always display in full even if the height is smaller then the original image?

EDITED CODE :

```css
.wrapped { position:relative; padding:0 20px; background:url(/Website6/Styles/leadgen_center.png); min-height: 205px; width:350px; }
.wrapped:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0; left:0; bottom:0; width:9px;
background:url(/Website6/Styles/leadgen_left.png);
}
.wrapped:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:9px;
background:url(/Website6/Styles/leadgen_right.png)
}
</style>
<div class="wrapped">
  <h3>
     This is the title
     </h3>        
     This is the description
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly like so, with no vapid markup elements required:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .wrapped { position:relative; padding:0 20px; background:url(center.png) }
  .wrapped:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0; width:20px;
    background:url(left.png)
  }
  .wrapped:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:20px;
    background:url(right.png)
  }
</style>
<div class="wrapped">Lots of text here</div>
```

Seen in action:

### http://jsfiddle.net/3Vb7F/

*Set the before/after widths to the size of your images; set the padding widths as desired, at least as wide as your images.*

Comment: So having a few problems with that. 1) On both the left and right side im seeing the left right image display mulitple times and to fill the div its like the center image is displaying after it to. 2) Because the is little text I can only see the top part of my center image so I cant the bottom shading of my image ?

Comment: @StevieB Update your question or add a comment with the URL to a simple pared-down test case showing the absolute minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Regarding resizing the background image based on the height of the container, you will need to use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) which is not well-supported among older browsers.

Comment: I added my edited code, the problem with right and left side at the moment is that the image are appearing where they should and aligned right next to center which is fine but then its like its trying to add the center image next to it again

Comment: @StevieB That was not a pared-down test case; that was a snippet of some code without any images we can compare against, all without the OS/browser/version where you're having trouble. It is very hard to help someone if you can't reproduce their problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use three images. If you use [the technique described here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/), you should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do and lose a lot of the hassle. You can try setting a line-height for the element if it's not tall enough.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! Ok im not sure how my example relates with the above if you could clarify ?

Comment: This should translate to what you want. It's basically a technique to set a background image that has a varying width.

Comment: Aye my problem I guess is I have three background images with varying width and height that I want to place next to eachother have the same height and width depending on content ?

Comment: Yeah I don't know where the confusion's coming in? Could you post a screenshot of what you're trying to do?